# Ubuntu 12.04 MySQL 5.5 MyODBC 5.1 or 3.1 query hangs

Tags: 12.04, mysql

I have been able to install Ubuntu 12.04 with LAMP MySQL version 5.5.x

It works fine within linux, it allows me to connect from myodbc windows vista or windows 7

I have configured networking access and have been able to access from windows vista using putty and other tcp connections like mysql query browser.

I have also configured or disabled ufw firewall and apparmor.

The connection works fine until I query data from the tables.

It lets me query small amounts of data like: `SELECT name FROM users` limit 20 but if I do a `SELECT * FROM users`, it goes on a never-ending loop. This happens even on tables with very few records like 5 or even less.

The problems occur with windows because I tried ssh from linux mint and it worked fine. I need to be able to work using MyODBC either 3.51 or 5.1 since my client program is made in VB6 and connects to mysql server via tcp/ip.

The server is an HP PROLIANT ML350G6 with Intel Xeon 64 bits.

I tried several ubuntu server version (12.04 64bit, 10.10 64bit, 11.04 32bit) and none has worked I even tried CentOS 6.3 and the same.

As a reference, it works fine with onother ubuntu server version 6.x on HP Proliant 150 and mysql 5.0.x that is like 7 years old and never updated.

Help Please.

Answer (score 1):

It is too bad nobody has responded to my question. 
I will add some new clues:

1) The queries work well from Windows XP to old and new MySQL linux versions on 32 or 64 bit server.
2) Windows Vista or 7 fails to query on the new MySQL versions

My guess is that newer Windows are sabotaging the queries on newer versions of MySQL/linux servers.

Could somebody tell me a possible solution or configuration fix.

Thanks.

Comment: Adding to my own comments:

Comment: The problem only happens on windows tcp/ip wireless. I tried on wired network and it works.

Comment: When I open an ssh connection with putty I log into ubuntu server fine, open small file fine, list with ls small directory fine, but if the directory is bigger than the screen page it will stall. Like ls /etc/ will stop on the first page and hang. Please help.

Comment: My real problem is wireless, I can connect and query the first results, apparently mysql sends all data but my windows screen halts at the first page. Would you kindly help? I need to be able to get all data through wireless on Windows Vista and Windows 7.

Comment: The weird thing is that it only fails on WiFi from Windows (tried from Vista and 7). It works when connected from Linux Mint WiFi.